# Mongoose Exclude a field if it doesn't match but not the doc

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got an invitation system and I want to know if the user has already been invited or not. Every time an user is invited, the notification array is updated with the targeted offer's id.

- Model

  ```
  ...
  notification:[
      {   offer: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Offer'},
          invitor:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
          createAt: {type:Date, default:Date.now()}
      }            
  ]
  ....
  ```

So my goal is when I query the user to display **notification field** if the offer's id is in the notification's array and not if it doesn't contain it.

Comment: See [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) ( projection form ). But unless you have something else to select the documents you want other than the array content then you would just be getting all documents, with empty arrays where the "offer" id does not match.

Comment: oh well seems to be working , thank you Blakes